# Passing Objects from Activity to ViewPager and then to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I am receiving a DataTransferBetweenActivity object from one Activity1 to Activity2. Activity2 has ViewPager and inside ViewPager I have 3 Fragments.  Here is the code of my adapter class for ViewPager

```
public class MusicPlayerTabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private DataTransferBetweenActivity data;
    private String PARCEL_KEY = "data";
    public MusicPlayerTabAdapter(FragmentManager fm, DataTransferBetweenActivity data) {
        super(fm);
        this.data = data;
        ArrayList list = data.getSongsList();
        Iterator<Song> it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Log.i("Reached", it.next().getTitle());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable(PARCEL_KEY, data);
                NowPlayingFragment nowPlayingFragment = new NowPlayingFragment();

                nowPlayingFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                return nowPlayingFragment;
            case 1:
                return new EqualizerFragment();
            case 2:
                return new LyricsFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Now inside NowPlayingFragment class i am getting null from getArguments(). Suggest the right way to do that. Here is my code of NowPlayingFragment

```
public class NowPlayingFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<Song> songsList;
    private int position;
    private String PARCEL_KEY = "data";
    private Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    private DataTransferBetweenActivity data = bundle.getParcelable(PARCEL_KEY);
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nowplaying_layout, container, false);
//        songsList = data.getSongsList();
//        position = data.getPosition();
        if(bundle == null)
        Log.i("Received DATA", "HELLO");
        return view;
    }
}
```

One more advice I need is that I will be adding MediaPlayerControls in my Activity2 and i want to change the song when i select a song from NowPlayingFragment which will be having a list of songs.
Suggest the correct way to build this functionality.

Comment: you should be calling `getArguments()` in the `onCreate` method of the fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `getArguments()` too early.

You should initialize variable `private Bundle bundle` in some method. For example, in `onCreate()`

```
public class NowPlayingFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<Song> songsList;
    private int position;
    private String PARCEL_KEY = "data";
    private Bundle bundle;
    private DataTransferBetweenActivity data;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        bundle = getArguments();
        data = bundle.getParcelable(PARCEL_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nowplaying_layout, container, false);
//        songsList = data.getSongsList();
//        position = data.getPosition();
        if(bundle == null)
        Log.i("Received DATA", "HELLO");
        return view;
    }
}
```